# Astro (Vite) compile separate SCSS files to external CSS files for use in other project

Tags: javascript, sass, vite, astrojs

I'm using the default Astro `npm create astro@latest` to create a static (frontend) **demo / prototype version of a web site** during development.

Later, our backend department will pick apart this static HTML version and rebuild it dynamically into a CMS for production.

### What I would like

- This would require that this Astro frontend demo site "shares" it's resources (assets), like CSS, images and font files etc., with the dynamic (backend) CMS version.
- It would be great while working on the Astro site (`yarn dev` or `npm dev`) to also have the below example be done in the background.
- Or, maybe have a separate **build** task that you can run later from `package.json`? Like `yarn build-prod` (`npm run build-prod`)

### Project SCSS structure

In Astro: I have a SCSS structure like this:

```
/src/styles/base/_variables.scss
/src/styles/header.scss
/src/styles/footer.scss
/src/styles/components/card.scss
/src/styles/components/carousel.scss
```

I would like Astro (Vite) to compile each SCSS file into CSS:

```
/public/styles/header.css
/public/styles/footer.css
/public/styles/components/card.css
/public/styles/components/carousel.css
```

Inside the Astro demo project, in the HTML head, we reference those compiled CSS files via HTML `<link rel="stylesheet" href="/styles/header.css">` etc. Note: I'm NOT using the `<style>` -tag inside a `*.astro` file.

I know this is not the way you use CSS in an Astro site. Because, we'd like to **SHARE the CSS stylesheets (and assets) with the dynamic CMS web site**.

Or is there a way to extract the SCSS from each `*.astro` file into separate named CSS equivalant component files: `components/card.astro` it's SCSS to `components/card.css`?

### Compile (or copy?) to the dynamic CMS version

In order for our dynamic CMS site to use the SAME stylesheets CSS files; have Astro (Vite) also "copy" (?) the CSS files and assets to:

```
/../../external/dir/of/cms/styles/header.css
/../../external/dir/of/cms/styles/footer.css
/../../external/dir/of/cms/styles/components/card.css
/../../external/dir/of/cms/styles/components/carousel.css
```

### Example Astro config file

Below is what I have so far in `astro.config.ts` to have (Vite?) compile the separate `*.scss` into `*.css`. There is output being generated. But, the output DOES NOT produce separate `*.css` files (only `header.scss` gets compiled). And, the static generated Astro build itself looks broken / incomplete.

```js
import { defineConfig } from 'astro/config';
import isWsl from "is-wsl";
import fg from 'fast-glob';
import { InputOption } from "rollup";

const rootSCSSEntries: InputOption = fg.sync([
    './src/styles/**/*.scss',
]).reduce((entryArr, entry) =>
    new Object({
        [entry.split('/').pop() ?? ""]: entry,
        ...entryArr
    }), {});

const inputOptions = {
    // example: './src/example.ts',
    ...rootSCSSEntries
} as InputOption;

// https://astro.build/config
export default defineConfig({
        vite: {
            css: {
                preprocessorOptions: {
                    scss: {
                        additionalData: `@import './src/styles/base/_variables.scss';`
                    }
                }
            },
            plugins: [],
            server: {
                watch: {
                    usePolling: isWsl
                }
            },
            // Set to empty to avoid warnings in yarn dev
            optimizeDeps: {
                include: []
            },
            build: {
                rollupOptions: {
                    input: inputOptions,
                    output: {
                        entryFileNames: '[name].ts',
                        assetFileNames: ({ name }) => {
                            if (/\.(gif|jpe?g|png|svg)$/.test(name ?? '')) {
                                return 'img/[name][extname]';
                            }

                            if (/\.(css|scss)$/.test(name ?? '')) {
                                return 'css/[name][extname]';
                            }

                            if (/\.(vue|js|ts|ce.vue)$/.test(name ?? '')) {
                                return 'js/[name][extname]';
                            }

                            // default value
                            // ref: https://rollupjs.org/guide/en/#outputassetfilenames
                            return 'builds/[name][extname]';
                        },
                        // dir: './dist'// Could be aiming to ../umbraco etc...
                        // -m is usually used in ci/cd
                        dir: './external/dir/of/cms/styles'
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
);
```

I'd still would like to have a working Astro statically build site in the `./dist` (as it normally does). Which still is used for demo and prototype purposes.

Thanks for reading this far. I know the above is pretty long and elaborate.